# add value in web page text box using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to add value in web page text box but getting object error.
I can't provide url as it will not work outside the office.

below html code:text box :

```
<input type="text" size="40" name="agent" id="go" value="">
```

Search :

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

VBA:

```
Sub login_page()     



    Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
            Dim iedoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            IEApp.Visible = True
            Set ieApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.navigate "http:/Login"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Set iedoc = ieApp.document

    with iedoc.forms(0)
    .user.Value = "id"
    .Password.Value = "Pass"
    .submit
    End With
    ieApp.navigate "http:action=view"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    'Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    ieApp.navigate "http:action=run"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop


    ieApp.navigate "http:Report?"
    action=run&category=interfaces&template=base%2Frouterprotocols&section=5"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    ieApp.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.location='Go?action=agent'"    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

let me help you.

```
  Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim elemnts   As Object
    Dim elem      As Object

    ie.Navigate url

    Do While ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While.
    Do Until ie.ReadyState >= 3: DoEvents: Call aceitaAlerta(False): Loop  'Do Until
    Set ELEMENTS = ie.Document.all
    For Each elem In ELEMENTS
         on error goto NextOne
         If elem.name = "agente" And elem.id = "go" Then
            elem.Value = "NEWVALUE"
            elem.innerText = "NEWVALUE"
            Exit For
         End If
NextOne:
    on error goto 0
    Next elem
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working ... getting error as object dosent support this property or method

Comment: Sub login_page()
Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set ieApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
ieApp.navigate "http:"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Set iedoc = ieApp.document
With iedoc.forms(0)
.user.Value = "id"
.Password.Value = "pass"
.submit
End With

Comment: ieApp.navigate "http:"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
ieApp.navigate "http:"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.navigate "http:"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
ieApp.document.parentWindow.execScript "window.location='Go?action=agent'"
End Sub

Comment: as i am not able to paste my code earlier hence paste here in two parts... please check and suggest

Comment: Dim elemnts   As Object
    Dim elem      As Object

 
    Set elements = ieApp.document.all
    For Each elem In elements
         On Error GoTo NextOne
         If elem.Name = "agents" And elem.ID = "go" Then
            elem.Value = "NEWVALUE"
            elem.innerText = "NEWVALUE"
            Exit For
         End If
NextOne:
    Next elem

Comment: but getting error on this line "If elem.Name = "agents" And elem.ID = "go" Then" as object dosent support this property or method

Comment: i have declare this objects in my code: Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set ieApp = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ieApp.Visible = True
Set iedoc = ieApp.document

Comment: .document.getElementById("go").value = "xyz" its not working ... please check my code...

Answer (score 0):

There is an id so use it

```
ieApp.document.getElementById("go")
```

Preceeding code

```
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = New  InternetExplorer
With ieApp
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "URL"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    .document.getElementById("go").value = "xyz"
End With
```

Comment: Have you found a solution  yet?